# Hide Volume Overlay While Setting Volume

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am attempting to set the volume to max on my initial view controller, while hiding the iOS volume overlay/hud.  For whatever reason, if I use this code in my .m file:

```
-(void)preventSystemVolumePopup {
    // Prevent Audio-Change Popus
    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-2000., -2000., 0.1f, 0.1f)];
    NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;

    volumeView.alpha = 0.1f;
    volumeView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];//set system vol to max


    if (windows.count > 0) {
       [[windows objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:volumeView];

    }
}
```

The volume doesn't change.  However, if I add the system volume change:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
```

To my viewDidLoad it works fine...except the volume overlay appears.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?  I've also tried adding a `UIview` in IB for `MPVolumeView` and sending that to the back of the view to hide, but it's still not hiding the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
```

it only work in device,not work in simulator

Comment: Thanks NANNAV, the setvolume command is working, I have that on line 8 in my code above....

The issue I'm having, is that if I put it within the 
-(void)preventSystemVolumePopup statement it does not work, the volume is not set to max.  However, if I put the setvolume code into my viewDidLoad it adjusts the volume but the volume HUD comes up.